# Time-driven lifetime scope in singleton ASP.NET Web API controller

Tags: autofac

Consider the web controller that implements some API by wrapping downstream service that requires token to be called. The token has the expiration, so I'm after some kind of time-driven scope that re-acquires the token and re-creates client in case  the token is expired:

```c#
MyController: Controller
{
    IServiceAPI _downstreamServcie;

    MyController (IServiceAPI downstreamService) 
    {
    }
}
.... 

builder.Register(c => {
Token token = generateToken() ..
return new ServiceAPIClient(token) ;
}) 
.As<IServiceAPI>()
```

I don't want to register `MyController` with per-request-scope because of performance issues.

Having spring background, such kind of `captive` dependency is resolved  in spring by injecting singleton dynamic proxy that forwards the call to the right scoped-object (request/session/custom).

What would be the right way to implement the same with Autofac?

Thanks

[UPDATE]

Digging  into Autofac documentation, I've found `IResolveMiddleware` interface that can be used to dynamically create/change scope :

```c#
class TokenScopeResolverMiddleware : IResolveMiddleware {
        private ISharingLifetimeScope _currentTokenScope;
        private ISharingLifetimeScope _prevTokenScope;

        public void Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action<ResolveRequestContext> next) {
            if (null == _currentTokenScope) {
                lock (this) {
                    if (null == _currentTokenScope) {
                        RolloverScope(context);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!CanUseCurrentToken()) {
                lock (this) {
                    if (!CanUseCurrentToken()) {
                        RolloverScope(context);
                    }
                }
            }

            context.ChangeScope(_currentTokenScope);
            next(context);
        }

        private bool CanUseCurrentToken() {
            AuthenticationResult authResult = _currentTokenScope.Resolve<AuthenticationResult>();

            TimeSpan expiresIn = authResult.ExpiresOn - DateTime.Now;
            return expiresIn > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        }

        private void RolloverScope(ResolveRequestContext context) {
            if (null != _prevTokenScope) {
                _prevTokenScope.Dispose();
            }
            _prevTokenScope = _currentTokenScope; // give another `expiration time` grace period before disposing token scope
            _currentTokenScope =
                context.ActivationScope.RootLifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("token") as ISharingLifetimeScope;
        }

        public PipelinePhase Phase { get; } = PipelinePhase.ScopeSelection;
    }
```

Usage :

```c#
           builder.Register(c => {
                    AuthenticationResult result = // acquire token
                    return result;
                })
                .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("token");

            builder.Register(c => {
                      return new Client(c.Resolve<AuthenticationResult>().Token)
                })
             .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("token");

             builder.RegisterServiceMiddleware<Client>(new TokenScopeResolverMiddleware());
```

Any better suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're likely looking for the `Func<T>` relationship, or something like it, where you inject a factory that dynamically resolves the client as you need it.

```cs
public class MyController
{
  private readonly Func<IClient> _clientFactory;
  public MyController(Func<IClient> clientFactory)
  {
     this._clientFactory = clientFactory;
  }
  public void DoWork()
  {
    var client = this._clientFactory();
    client.CallApi();
  }
}
```

Your lambda could be just about anything as long as it runs synchronously. Don't forget DI is more about injecting dependencies (object construction) than it is about managing your application's state, orchestrating logic, or executing factories on your behalf, though admittedly it's pretty convenient to try to multipurpose it in those ways.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
  var token = GetOrRefreshToken();
  return new Client(token);
}).As<IClient>();
```

A word of warning - **you may run into memory leak trouble**.

If the `IClient` implementation is also `IDisposable`, Autofac is going to [hold onto every `IClient` created until the lifetime scope is disposed](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html) because the container is responsible for creating objects... and disposing them. If your controller is a singleton, that means the `Func<IClient>` will be resolving from the root lifetime scope (the container itself), which further means you can't dispose the captured `IClient` instances without disposing the whole application container.

You can [disable that with `ExternallyOwned`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#disabling-disposal) but then you also will have to dispose things yourself.

It may be better to unwind things just a little and try to do less in DI, more with your own code. For example, *actually create your own client factory* that knows when to refresh the token, how to construct and dispose of clients, etc. You may even want to look at stuff like [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) which is specifically meant for stuff like this. Then instead of injecting the client, inject the factory and use the factory to get a client instance as you need it. That is, instead of injecting `Func<IClient>`, inject `IHttpClientFactory` or something similar, thus reducing the need to try to force the captive dependency to behave and instead addressing the challenge with a solution possibly more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I really want to keep the controller as dummy as possible, think about the auto discovered module that sets things up without requiring the user (controller)  to do nothing else than configuring the needed credentials. If I give up and do use controller per request (really not filling comfortable with this) what would be your suggestion? I was thinking about custom  pool implementation that resolves single client till it is valid, or maybe filter that recreates scope once current token gets expired. The solution should serve many applications with minimal setup efforts

Comment: I think my answer remains the same: try to avoid the captive dependency for the client, look at things like `IHttpClientFactory`, and be careful of object lifetime/memory leak issues. You mentioned Spring, which makes me think Java - things may be solved in a different way in .NET. Unfortunately there are to many "what if I do X, how will it change?" options here, we can't "iterate" over the solution. Based on what you asked, the answer I gave is what I can offer.

Comment: I've updated my question with my current implementation, will appreciate your comment on this @travis-illig